# Is there a solution or package for this design with React js?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I have a mock up design from client that looks like this: [mockup design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJUNk.png)

The idea is that we have a couple of tests, which are Virtual Shelf and so on, and we have tools for solving these tests, which are Mouse Click, Emotion Recognition etc.

How can I make the design of these lines from the test to it's children ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example includes an API, to easily manipulate the values:

```
$listify: (
   "ul": (
      paddingLeft: 1rem,
      "li": (
         gap: 0.5rem,
         strikeColor: #000,
         strikeWidth: 1px,
         v-strikeGap: .5rem,
         v-strikeLength: .5rem
      )
   )
);

ul.listify {
   $mapScope: map-get($listify, "ul");
   list-style: none;
   margin: 0;
   padding-left: map-get($mapScope, paddingLeft);
   > li {
      $mapScope: map-get($mapScope, "li");
      line-height: 1;
      padding-bottom: map-get($mapScope, gap);
      padding-left: calc(#{map-get($mapScope, v-strikeLength)} + #{map-get($mapScope, v-strikeGap)});
      padding-top: map-get($mapScope, gap);
      position: relative;
      &::before,
      &::after {
         content: "";
         left: 0;
         position: absolute;
         width: map-get($mapScope, v-strikeLength);
      }
      &::before {
         border-left: map-get($mapScope, strikeWidth) solid map-get($mapScope, strikeColor);
         border-bottom: map-get($mapScope, strikeWidth) solid map-get($mapScope, strikeColor);
         height: calc(0.5em + #{map-get($mapScope, gap)});
         top: 0;
      }
      &:not(:last-of-type) {
         &::after {
            border-left: map-get($mapScope, strikeWidth) solid map-get($mapScope, strikeColor);
            height: 100%;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This compiles to:

```css
ul.listify {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 1rem;
}
ul.listify > li {
  line-height: 1;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
  position: relative;
}
ul.listify > li::before, ul.listify > li::after {
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0.5rem;
}
ul.listify > li::before {
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  height: calc(0.5em + 0.5rem);
  top: 0;
}
ul.listify > li:not(:last-of-type)::after {
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
   Title
   <ul class="listify">
      <li>Foo</li>
      <li>Bar</li>
      <li>
         Foobar
         <ul class="listify">
            <li>Foo</li>
            <li>Bar</li>
            <li>Foobar</li>
         </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to generate a vertical menu:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>VERTICAL MENU TREE WITH LINE</title>
    <style>
        .menu-items li {
    padding: 9px 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.menu-items li.active a {
    color: red;
    font-weight 700
}

.sub-items {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

.sub-items li {
    position: relative;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
}

.sub-items li::before {
    position: relative;
    top: -4px;
    width: 15px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
}

.sub-items li:last-of-type {
    border-left: none;
}

.sub-items li:last-of-type:after {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 18px;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
}
    </style>
    
</head>
<body>
<ul class="menu-items">
    <li>
    <a href="#">Example 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="#">Tree</a>
    <ul class="sub-items">
        <li>
        <a href="#">Item 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="#">Item2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="#">Example 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="#">Example 3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```